# how to use file parameter in jenkins workflow

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Does the file parameter work at all in a workflow job? If so, please explain how to do so.

When I add a `file parameter` under `This build is parameterized` in a workflow, it won't be uploaded. The parameter/variable will contain the file name though. While in a `free style project` an upload "step" is shown during a build.

`jenkins (1.617)`,
`workflow (1.8)`

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe file parameters can be made to work currently, as described in [JENKINS-27413](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413).

Comment: Ok. Any advise to tackle this in another way? E.g. trigger workflow job in a freestyle job (need to be able to stream a file from another environment). Using a workflow string parameter as the file location on a network drive.

Comment: However, trigger another job with CLI in a batch script step is very ugly.

Comment: Until [JENKINS-26050](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26050) or [JENKINS-28071](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28071) is implemented, that is not going to be easy as a workaround I am afraid. Currently you can only use the REST API to trigger a downstream workflow job.